# Is it possible to work developer console for user?

Tags: developer-console

It's might be old things but I am new for this things I need to know why user not able to access developer console. Is it possible to create anyway in sales force? please give me the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to manage user and give then "view all data access" then they can see developer console in their org.

Answer (score 1):

To use Developer Console the user should have “View All Data” permissions. You could find more details about Developer Console access at https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_system_log.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this link https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=When-using-Login-access-why-can-I-see-the-Developer-Console-for-a-standard-user&language=en_US

if a user does not have Author Apex, and View All then no they would not be able to see the Developer Console in the drop down under name.